# How to avoid 'ID Not Found in Layout' with initial loading of app?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

The below code functions correctly. The problem is that upon the initial loading of the app, the ID of the datatable cannot be found. I believe this is because it has not yet been created.

How do I avoid this errror?

```
from dash import dash, dash_table, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('start', id='button1'),
    html.Button('start', id='button2'),
    html.Div(id='div1'),
    html.Div(id='div2')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('div1', 'children'),
    Input('button1', 'n_clicks'),
)
def generate_upload_file(n_clicks):  
    if n_clicks:
        df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminder2007.csv')
        data_dict = df.to_dict('records')
        headers_list = list(df.columns.values)
        headers_dict = ([{'id': _, 'name': _} for _ in headers_list])
        return dash_table.DataTable(
            id='datatable1',
            data=data_dict,
            columns=headers_dict,
            filter_action="native",
            sort_action="native",
            sort_mode="multi",
            row_deletable=True,
            page_action="native",
            page_current= 0,
            page_size= 10,
        )
    else: raise PreventUpdate


@app.callback(
    Output('div2', 'children'),
    Input('button2', 'n_clicks'),
    State('datatable1', 'data'),
    )
def create_df(n_clicks, datatable_rows):  
    if n_clicks:
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datatable_rows)
        print(df)
    else: raise PreventUpdate

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting suppress_callback_exceptions = True inside the app object. You'll still get the warning when in debug mode but the app should work fine.

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__,suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
```